# Link body part to a view generated with a show action and containing not only text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner in Rails.
I'm following this tutorial: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
The Article database contains my differents articles. The body part is waiting for some text. Instead of showing text in the body, I need to show some tables and graphics in the body part. Each article (which are pages for me) will contain different graphics, statistics or tables depending of the article.
How can I do that? Do the body part must be in a separated view, and the link contained in the article databse? I'm sure, things are easier with Rails, but I don't find how.
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If one article can have an arbitrary amount of tables, graphics etc. you most likely need to create one (or more) additional database tables. I think that reading https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html might give you a good start to dig deeper into this topic. You might end up with something like:

```
class Article
  has_many :tables
end

class Table
  belongs_to :article
end
```

Then in your view you could iterate over `@article.tables`.

Please note: just copying the code above will not do any good. You will need to dig a bit deeper into rails. I'd recommend to follow some (modern) tutorial diving deeper into the case of having associations between different Models. Something like: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCEzxY9BbiU

While stackoverflow is good for asking specific questions, more general Questions like this can probably best be answered by digging deeper, following various tutorials. It takes a while to become confident in any technology, rails is no exception.

Update: Actually the "Getting started"-Guide you've been following is adding a second model later on as well: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#adding-a-second-model .While here it will be "Comments", it would be very similar to add `Figures` or something like that.

Comment: Exactly, my articles will have ann arbitrary amount of tables and graphics. So I will create the other tables needed. I understood the principe of association between different Models, but all the time, theses Models are made for "text". Text that you can record in databases. My datas come from queries from sql server. I know how to display them on a static page, but I don't know where to record the html code calling the resulting datas to display them in the table or graphics.

Comment: here's an example of code '            <table width="90%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
              <% @workflow_visualisation.each do |row| %>
                <tr>
                  <td style="width: 20%" border="1"><%= row['PatientId'] %></td>
                  <td style="width: 20%" border="1"><%= row['LastName'] %></td>
                  <td style="width: 20%" border="1"><%= row['FirstName'] %></td>
                  <td style="width: 20%" border="1"><%= row['ActivityCode'] %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end  %>
            </table>'

Comment: @Chamard33 I am not sure If I completely understand your use-case. You have an `Article` and for this Article you want to store pre-created pieces of html for later display? I would not recommend to do this, but rather to find a proper data structure for the underlying data, and render the html on the fly.